# How to Run the Index Function from within Script vs. inside Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a use case where I need to run the index function from within the code vs. within the cell of the spreadsheet.

Use case is as follows:

- Take Responses from Form
- Apply logic based on combination of answers to calculate score for each question (this is where I need to use an Index function to look up the table which assists with the calculations)

  - Questions are grouped (Group A, Group B, Group C, etc.)
  - If Answer to Group A, Question 1 is "No", then Overall score for that group will be forced to 0.  All questions in Group A will still get a separate score, but the group score is still 0.
  - If Answer to Group A, Question 1 is "Yes", then Overall score is an average of all scores received on questions in that group

In excel VBA this would have been done by using:
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(..., ..., ...)

Does any such functionality exist inside google script for google sheets?
I have tried to code this on my own, and while I can get it work from within the code, I can't get it to return correctly inside the sheet.

```
function udfINDEX(str_ROW, str_COL) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // FORM Responses are on this tab
  var form = app.getSheetByName("Form Responses");

  // Calculations are occuring on this tab
  var xlte = app.getSheetByName("Translated Responses");

  // Points value for each Question and Override logic listed on this tab
  var vals = app.getSheetByName("Values");

  var i_row = udfMATCH(str_ROW.getValue(), 'r');
  var i_col = udfMATCH(str_COL.getValue(), 'c');

  var ans = form.getRange(i_row, i_col, 1, 1)

  return String(ans).trim(); 
}

function udfMATCH(strFIND, strTYPE) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var form = app.getSheetByName("Form Responses");

  if ( strTYPE === "r" ) {
    return udfROW(strFIND, form.getLastRow());
  } else {
    return udfCOL(strFIND, form.getLastColumn());
  } 
}

// Always a TimeStamp 
function udfROW(strFIND, iMaxRow) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var form = app.getSheetByName("Form Responses");

  for (var i = 1; i <= iMaxRow; i++) {
      var findDTE = String(strFIND).trim()
      var compareDTE = String(form.getRange(i, 1, 1, 1).getValue()).trim();

      if ( compareDTE == findDTE ) {
        return i;
        break;
      } else if ( compareDTE.length == 0 ) {
        return NaN;
        break;
      }
  }
}


// Each Column has Unique Value or Header
function udfCOL(strFIND, iMaxCol) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var form = app.getSheetByName("Form Responses");

  var i = 1

  for (var j = 1; j <= iMaxCol; j++) {
    var findCOL = String(strFIND).trim();
    var compareCOL = String(form.getRange(1, j, 1, 1).getValue()).trim();

    if ( compareCOL == findCOL ) {
        return j;
        break;
    } else if ( compareCOL.length == 0 ) {
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why? Explain your use case. Unlike excel, where formulas and macros are merged, Js is a different language requiring rethinking of ground logic. Also "can't get it to return correctly" is not a problem description. Read [mcve] and describe  the problem.

Comment: What exact index are you talking about? At first look I see problems in your code you call multiple times `SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` and `app.getSheetByName("Form Responses");` what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: can you share your spreadsheet I will be happy to help you live with this?

Comment: `udf` `INDEX` might seem right for you, coming from VBA.. But there are plenty of things wrong with your entire approach. Given the limited information, The flow of your script should be 1. script function should be triggered [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4) > get FormResponse object > get [itemResponses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response) > get item> ``if(item.getTitle()=="Question 1"&& itemResponse.getResponse()=="No"{var score =0} else{ //calculate other responses}`` Review Best practices.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices As far as what's wrong with your code, There seems to be lot of type errors. For ex `var ans = form.getRange(i_row, i_col, 1, 1)` returns range object. You're returning `String(ans)` , which will return range object-not it's value. Other than that as @Jsmith said there are plenty of code repeats, ``getValue()``... Use arrays `getValues()`,`setValues()` instead. If you're calling from inside the sheet as a custom function, there's no way your function will run within the 30 second limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. It worked in my simple example. Perhaps it will work in yours. I'm not that familiar with cell formulas except for Array Formulas.

```
function mySum(a,b){
  var a=a || 'A1';
  var b=b || 'B1';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var v1=sh.getRange(a).getValue();
  var v2=sh.getRange(b).getValue();
  var cell=sh.getActiveCell();
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(' + a + "," + b + ')');
  var v3=cell.getValue();
  return cell.getValue();
}
```